# How to make display the recently appended data of a file in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing something to a file at a particular time interval and I am sending that file's data to my mail.

So my command is,

```
cat $file | mailx -s "Subject" $to_addr
```

But this gives all the file content. How to get the newly added / lastly appended data of a file?

Is this possible?

Comment: cant you tail it? `tail -f $file`

Comment: You can use the `tail` command to get last N rows of the file. You could also remember (in another file) the size of the file at the time it was last sent and read from that position on, but that is beyond my bash abilities.

Comment: Yes. We could use the `tail`. But I am using this in a script. If i used the tail command, the script is not ending.

Comment: Aren't the commands which are _writing something to a file_ and the `mailx` command in the same script? Otherwise you'd have to define _newly / lastly_ - since when?